# What defines formation compatibility in FIFA '13 Ultimate Team?

Tags: fifa-13

In Fifa 13's Ultimate Team mode, every player (card) has a preferred formation. Every squad is playing in some formation (obviously). When a player card is placed in a squad, the formation compatibility is evaluated. It may receive one of three ratings.

[image: Green Formation Compatibility] - Full formation compatibility, provides bonus to Chemistry. This is only awarded if formations of squad and a given player are exactly the same.

[image: Orange Formation Compatibility] - Formations are somewhat compatible, seems to be neutral to Chemistry.

[image: Red Formation Compatibility] - Formations are too different, gives a Chemistry penalty.

Now, the rules that decide whether a formation of a player is at least somewhat compatible with the squad's elude me. **What are they?**

Answer (score 2):

The formation needs to be a variation on the preferred formation.

For example, a player who is suited to a 4-4-2 may work well in a 4-4-1-1 as it is a variation, but not well in a 3-4-3.

Comment: True, I managed to observe that much. The troubling concept is what  constitutes a variation worthy of the middle rating. Some ideas that didn't pan out in practice were "same family" (3-, 4-, 5- prefixes) or "same amount of players in the player's tier (defense, middle or attack)". This question looks to clarify what exactly decides between the two latter ratings.

Comment: What exactly decides will be different for each formation, it wont be a universal rule. The prefix you describe is just the number of defenders, so it is no surprise it is not linked to that.